# Change text msg after 5 star vote (maybe animated)

Tags: jquery, text, replace, slider

Im seeking help to do a "text roll/replace" and even better if animated.

To the point i have a vote with 5 stars, once people have clicked on the rating, star 1, 2, 3.. etc

At first i want to show msg: "Like it or not?" once voted text change to, "thumbs up pal!" and seconds after changing to "2 rating from 1 vote"

Hope it makes sense? :)

Answer (score 1):

- Use [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) for effects.
- Use the [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) function to do things after a couple of seconds.